# ERROR Button which can duplicate item in javascript : no display of value

Tags: javascript, haml

I'm new in javascript and I need to create a duplicate button for my project : I have a checkbox list with different type of findings and when one of them is check I want to have a button to duplicate this finding. 
I did something like this :

```
%input.checkbox#finding_id{ :type=>"checkbox", :name=>"#{finding.id}" }

%a.btn.btn-success#addd{ :href => "#", :onclick => "duplicate()" }
%i.icon-plus.icon-white{ :title => "Add" }

:javascript
 document.getElementById('addd').click = duplicate;
 var i = 0;
 var original = document.getElementById('inf_#{finding.id}');

 function duplicate() {
 var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
 clone.id = "inf_#{finding.id}" + ++i;
 original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
 }
```

But I think I have a syntax problem, it didn't recognize the "inf_#{finding.id}" which create dynamic ID for each row in haml.

Comment: Are you sure an element with the id `finding_id` exists?

Comment: It's ok  I add finding_id now but I have an other problem : When I click on button it only create the checkbox, it doesn't copy the value of the checkbox

Comment: Please show **all** of the relevant code

Comment: Here is my update

Comment: Here is my update of the code and the result

Comment: I'm not sure what your screenshot is supposed to show, as all 3 checkboxes are checked. Having said that, you may need to set the `checked` property yourself

Comment: When I try to add the finding, it only display the checkbox but it doesn't take into account the value : the title, the information about the finding ...

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your last screenshot it seems like your checkbox is in a table therefore when you select it you don't have the entire row but only the element in the column.
I would suggest you to learn about [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to achieve your goal of copying the entire row. You can use functions such as:
 `document.querySelector("your Css selector here !")` to get the DOM node you want.

Correct my if I'm wrong but I think there is no easy way to select the parent node of an element. Lets say you have this table:

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>Label</th>
    <th>Level</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="firstCheckbox"></td>
    <td>My first checkbox</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="secondCheckbox"></td>
    <td>My second checkbox</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You might not be able to get the entire row by getting checkbox element itself since you can't get its parent node. Therefore you might want to change your table so it is easier to work with:

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>Label</th>
    <th>Level</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="myFirstRow">
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>My first checkbox</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="mySecondRow">
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>My second checkbox</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now you can easily get your row with this JS code:
`var secondRow = document.querySelector("#mySecondRow");`

This might not be the best option here but it is just to give you an exemple of what you can do with Css Selector.

Since you're new to JS you should go ahead and have a look on w3schools website since it contains a lot of information.

Edit: As Chris Satchell says, you can still get it in JavaScript (using parentNode): document.getElementById('firstCheckbox').parentNode.

Comment: You can get the parent node (using `parentNode`): `document.getElementById('firstCheckbox').parentNode.parentNode.children` would return all `td`s

Comment: Hello thanks for your help ! I added an id in my <tr> to have an id for each row. But now I have an other problem : I try to  generate dynamic values to have a different ID for each row : row 1 id=1; row 2 id=2 etc... It works in my haml but it didn't recognize it in my JavaScript. Have you got a solution to write it properly ? I updated my first post with more informations.